# Не получается добавить аудио

Tags: java

Добавил в код:

```
public static synchronized void playSound(final String url) {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
  // The wrapper thread is unnecessary, unless it blocks on the
  // Clip finishing; see comments.
    public void run() {
      try {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
          Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/sounds/" + url));
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.start(); 
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }).start();
}
```

Выходит ошибка "java: illegal start of expression".
Выделяет красным final и url:

```
  public static synchronized void playSound(final String url) {
```

Что это может значить?

---

Поменял код.
Вынес метод playSound за метод main.
И добавил название метода playSound в метод main, чтобы вызвать playSound:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        playSound(final String url);
        }
```

Выходит ошибка "java: illegal start of expression". Выделяет красным final и url уже в методе main:

```
playSound(final String url);
```

Что не так?

Файл я указал вот так:

```
Main.class.getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\Ученик\\IdeaProjects\\test\\src\\audio\\ghost.wav" + url));
```

---

Удалил url и добавил адрес:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        playSound("C:\\Users\\powha\\Documents\\CTT\\ЗАНЯТИЯ\\Конкурсы\\test\\src\\audio\\skeleton.wav");
    }
    public static synchronized void playSound(final String name) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                            Main.class.getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\powha\\Documents\\CTT\\ЗАНЯТИЯ\\Конкурсы\\test\\src\\audio\\skeleton.wav"));
                    clip.open(inputStream);
                    clip.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

В итоге выдает в консоли null.

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

---

Заменил на new FileInputStream("ваш_абсолютный_путь.wav"):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\powha\\Documents\\CTT\\ЗАНЯТИЯ\\Конкурсы\\test\\src\\audio\\skeleton.wav");
    }
}
```

Выдает:

"C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-16\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:C:\Users\powha\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.2\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\powha\Documents\CTT\ЗАНЯТИЯ\Конкурсы\test\out\production\test;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" Main
Connected to the target VM, address: '', transport: 'socket'

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

Comment: При *вызове* метода НЕ нужно указывать тип и аргументы, как при определении.  Достаточно было написать `playSound("название_файла_со_звуком");`

Comment: Также переменная 'url' НЕ определена в методе `main` в показанном коде.

Comment: В playSound указал путь к файлу и указал переменную "name" вместо url. Выдает, что null.

Comment: Проблема скорей всего в том, что вы пытаетесь прочитать звуковой файл как ресурс в jar-файле при помощи `getResourceAsStream`, а указываете абсолютный путь на файловой системе.  Разумеется, такой файл не будет найден.  Попробуйте заменить на `new FileInputStream("ваш_абсолютный_путь.wav")`

Comment: Хм.. заменил. все равно тишина..

Comment: Ошибки появляются какие-то?  Проверяли ли в отладчике как был прочитан аудиоклип?

Comment: В debugger выдает: "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
"

Comment: И еще: ""C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-16\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:C:\Users\powha\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.2\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\powha\Documents\CTT\ЗАНЯТИЯ\Конкурсы\test\out\production\test;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" Main
Connected to the target VM, address: '', transport: 'socket'"

Comment: В последнем коде вы просто создали поток чтения из файла и ничего не прочитали оттуда.  Следовало использовать этот поток в вызове `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream`.  Можете в процессе отладки распечатать формат прочитанного файла `AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat`

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Можете показать пример кода?

Comment: [Пример кода онлайн](https://ideone.com/PAH3LD)

Comment: Добавил. Теперь пишет: "Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
 at java.base/java.io.InputStream.reset(InputStream.java:733)
 at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.SunFileReader.getAudioFileFormat(SunFileReader.java:59)
 at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.SunFileReader.getAudioFileFormat(SunFileReader.java:47)
 at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(AudioSystem.java:922)
 at Ideone.main(Ideone.java:13)"

Comment: В таком случае следует гуглить ошибку, возможное решение - обернуть дополнительно поток ввода в `BufferedInputStream`, [как описано на основном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5529906/13279831)

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, ты вставил этот код внутрь другого метода, а не какого-либо класса. Как раз в таком случае компилятор выдает такую ошибку.

**UPD:** Кажется, ты все еще не решил проблему. Можешь залить код на какой нибудь pastebin и отправить ссылку? А то так помочь почти невозможно.

Comment: Поменял код, но все равно нет звука..

Comment: Вот код в pastebin https://pastebin.com/gwnxU1Z1          
В scr находится класс Main. Весь код в нем. 
И еще в src папка audio. В ней файл skeleton.wav . 

На консоли выдает null.

В debugger выдает OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
null